# Find the number of trailing zeros of $\binom{2020}{1234}$

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of trailing zeros of $\binom{2020}{1234}$.

I first got the number of trailing zeros of $2020!$, $786!$, and $1234!$, which are $503$, $195$, and $305$. I added the second and the third and I subtracted from the first and gave me $3$, but the correct answer was $2$.

Comment: The correct answer to which question?

Comment: @Bernard, the question is in the title.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/272831) After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: As for a hint, $10/(2\times5)$ has no trailing zeros.

Answer (score 5):

Given a prime $p$, we know that $p^m\lVert k!$ for $m=\sum_{j=1}^\infty\left\lfloor \frac{k}{p^j}\right\rfloor$.

Thus \begin{align}2020!&=2^{2013}\cdot 5^{503} a\\ 1234!&=2^{1229}\cdot 5^{305} b\\ 786!&=2^{782}\cdot 5^{195} c\end{align}

With $a,b,c$ coprime with $10$ and such that $\frac a{bc}\in\Bbb N$. Therefore $$\binom{2020}{1234}=2^{2013-1229-782}\cdot 5^{503-305-195}\frac{a}{bc}=2^2\cdot 5^3\cdot\frac a{bc}=10^2\cdot \frac{5 a}{bc}$$

and $\frac{5a}{bc}$ is odd.

Basically, the point is that $\max(x,y)-\max(z,w)$ needs not be larger than $\min(x,y)-\min(z,w)$, therefore one cannot focus only on the exponent of $5$.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Kummer’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem), the binomial coefficient $\binom nk$ contains exactly as many factors of a prime $p$ as carries arise in the digital addition of $m$ and $n-m$ in base $p$.

In the present case, we have $n=2020$, $m=1234$, thus $n-m=786$, and

\begin{eqnarray}
1234_{10}&=&14414_5\;,\\
786_{10}&=&11121_5\;,\\
2020_{10}&=&11111100100_2\;,\\
786_{10}&=&\hphantom{0}1100010010_2\;.
\end{eqnarray}

So there are $3$ carries in the addition in base $5$ and $2$ carries in the addition in base $2$, and thus exactly $2$ factors of $10$ in the coefficient.

The error in your calculation was the assumption that the counts of the composite factor $10$ can be added and subtracted like the counts of prime factors. The number of factors of $10$ in a number is the minimum of the numbers of factors of $2$ and $5$, and this minimum is not additive.